# iphone - Getting data from uiwebview textfield

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

Am developing an app which load a HTML page into uiwebview - that html file contains text-filed and drop-down list, text-boxes etc..

Here How to get values which user has entered in that text-filed and answers selected from drop-down(picker).

Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use `[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:]` method and get the values by executing the javascript.

Example:
If your html is:

```
<html>
  <body>
      <input id="myId" type="text" value="TextValue"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Following code can get you the value of the text field:

```
   NSString* value = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('myId').value"];
```

Comment: is there any way to pass to content to uiwebview and reloading the web view while app is running...?

Comment: @niki I think everything comes with the ability to execute the javascript in the webview. In the previous example, to set the value in the text field you can do [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('myId').value = 'newValue'"]. Similarly, you can reload using javascript or using the load methods in webview.

Comment: could you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793698/how-to-make-image-maps-clickable-using-uiwebview-in-iphone

Answer (score 4):

You can either poll a javascript function inside the page (using [UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW21)).

Or you could call an objective-c method directly from the page using a little hack: [UIWEBVIEW SECRETS - PART3 - HOW TO PROPERLY CALL OBJECTIVEC FROM JAVASCRIPT](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript)

(scroll down to the bottom for github-link).

Answer (score 3):

If HTML response is this,

```
<html>
  <body>
      <input id="myId" type="hidden" value="TextValue"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

So you can access like this in **Swift**,

```
  var id:String = IBwebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('myId').value")!
  println(id)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this when its a class instead of an id? Also is there a way to get the value of an attribute in particular?

Comment: Yes, to getting value for class instead of id use `getElementsByClassName` method instead of `getElementById`.

Comment: What about getting the value of an attribute of an element, like <div class="hey" active="false">, like attribute active in this case, how do you do this?

Comment: I wrote a question here was curious if you might know the answer to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840196/get-attribute-from-div-element-into-my-ios-app-from-uiwebview-w-swift), explains my situation and how it differs a bit from what is happening here.

Comment: How do you do this in Swift 3 with the new WKWebView?

Answer (score 0):

With the new `WKWebView` class, given this response:

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <input id="myId" type="text" value="TextValue"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

You'd access it like this in Swift:

```swift
view.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('myId').value") { result, _ in
    // do something with `result`
}
```