# Getting data from uiwebview textfield ANDROID?

Tags: android, uiwebview

Hi i am developing an app which load a HTML page into uiwebview - that html file contains text-filed and drop-down list, text-boxes etc.

Here How to get values which user has entered in that text-filed and answers selected from drop-down(picker).

Else is there any way to read response from a webpage?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the values typed in in input tags of a form element which are send with POST or GET to a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specifically do not have access to these values. This is part of how the OAuth authentication that facebook uses when you sign in with facebook to third party apps manages to be secure.

If an app developer could pull information from the webview where you enter your facebook username and password while signing into their app "with facebook", it would be a totally insecure model.

If its your own website that the webview is loading, you could potentially have it send the values to the device in a few different ways, but if for example you are sending them to google.com, you cannot see what they entered into any textfields.

Comment: but it can be done in IOS I dont agree with it.?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908775/iphone-getting-data-from-uiwebview-textfield