# Getting data from a UIWebView Text View to reload

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm well aware of the other example for getting back data from a text view using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript`, but I am not seeing any text reloading after I type.

[Getting Data From UIwebView Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908775/iphone-getting-data-from-uiwebview-textfield)

Here is what I have:

```
  var id:String = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('user_login').value")!
  print(id)
```

`print(id)` is never being called or changed.

Here is my where I'm getting it from:

```
<input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" aria-    describedby="login_error" class="input" value="" size="20">
```

Nothing happens when I type into the text field. Is my javascript script wrong.

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full code.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://hm-frontend-staging.herokuapp.com/wp-login.php?loggedout=true")!))


   webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: webView)

}



func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

   print(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('user_login').value")!)
}

func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}
```

Comment: can you post more code?

Comment: @jacobbullock sure.

Comment: you should make calls to stringByEvaluatingJavaScript when you know the web view has loaded the content in webViewDidFinishLoad

Comment: Ah, so maybe use GCD, or a callback

Comment: well if you use webViewDidFinishLoad you don't need to use the callback, webViewDidFinishLoad is the delegate method that essentially is the callback

Comment: Ya I'm still having problem, I'll edit my question to show you what I have